# Сохранение Сustom Objects через NSUserDefaults

Tags: массивы, ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

НЕ МОГУ СОХРАНИТЬ через NSUserDefaults значения собранные чекмаркером для передачи на др контроллер в конкретную ячейку таблицы
(КОД ПО СОХРАНЕНИЮ УЖЕ ИСПРАВЛЕН)
    import UIKit

```
class Exersise: NSObject, NSCoding { 
var name: String
var image: String
var checked: Bool

init(name: String, image: String, checked: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.checked = checked
}
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    self.image = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as! String
    self.checked = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("checked") as! Bool
}
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    [aCoder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")]
    [aCoder.encodeObject(self.image, forKey: "image")]
    [aCoder.encodeObject(self.checked, forKey: "checked")]
}
}
// Эта функция обязательно должна быть глобальной и требуется протоколом Equatable, без неё компилятор будет ругаться, что структура не соответствует протоколу.
func ==(lhs: Exersise, rhs: Exersise) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.image == rhs.image
}

var exersise = [Exersise]() // заменяем tuple на класс

class AllExersiseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//создаем секции
struct Objects {
    var sectionName: String!
    var sectionObjects: [Exersise]!
}
var objectsArray = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Элементы секций
objectsArray = [
    Objects(sectionName: "Standing", sectionObjects: [
        Exersise(name: "Приседания", image:"bb", checked: false),
        Exersise(name: "Отжимания", image:"bt", checked: false)]),
    Objects(sectionName: "Sitting", sectionObjects: [
            Exersise(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru", checked: false),
            Exersise(name: "ПРЫЖКИ", image:"al", checked: false)]),
    Objects(sectionName: "Sitting", sectionObjects: [
            Exersise(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru", checked: false),
            Exersise(name: "ПРЫЖКИ", image:"al", checked: false)])]
}
```

Выбор из списка необходимых элементов чекмаркером для сохранения и передачи

```
    //нажатие на ячейку
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return } // убеждаемся, что ячейка правильная

    let object = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    if object.checked {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
        object.checked = false
        if let index = exersise.indexOf(object) { // находим реальный индекс объекта в массиве
            exersise.removeAtIndex(index) // удаляем объект по правильному индексу
        }
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        object.checked = true
        exersise.append(object) //добавляем в массив элементы ячейки
    }
```

дальше в алерте сохраняем выбранные элементы и создаем название ячейки в которую будем передавать выбранные элементы

```
            workout.append(self.nameWorkoutTextField.text!)//текст получаем из текстфилда, оно работает
            self.nameWorkoutTextField.text = ""
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(workout, forKey: "workout")//создаем название ячейки

            let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(exersise)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "Exersise")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() //сохраняем выбранные элементы
```

Далее контроллер в котором отображаются созданные ячейки с выбранными из списка элементами. В каждой новой ечейке должны храниться соответственно конкретно для нее выбранные элементы

```
var workout = [String]()//вынесен за класс контроллера

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("workout") != nil  {
        workout = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("workout") as! [String]
    }//читаем название ячейки

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("exersise") != nil  {
                let newData: NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Exersise") as! NSData
    let newArr: Array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(newData) as! [Exersise]

    let newObject: Exersise = newArr[0]
    print(newObject.name)
    print(newObject.image)//читаем выбранные элементы для этой ячейки

}
```

Отображаем ячейку

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    myCell.textLabel?.text = workout[indexPath.row]

    return myCell
}
```

Список элементов для этой ячейки отображать не надо, но при нажатию на эту ячейку переходим на др контроллер в котором уже отобразим список элементов этой ячейки. НЕ ПОЙМУ МЕХАНИЗМ КАК ПРИСВОИТЬ ВЫБРАННЫЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ К КОНКРЕТНО СОЗДАВАЕМОЙ ДЛЯ НИХ ЯЧЕЙКИ, ПОТОМУ ЧТО СЕЙЧАС ПРИ СОЗДАНИИ НЕСКОЛЬКИХ ЯЧЕЕК И ЗАХОДЕ В НИХ, ОНИ ОТОБРАЖАЮТ ОДИН И ТОТ ЖЕ СПИСОК ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ

Comment: можно как то это все сократить до той части, с которой нужна помощь? у вас сохраненный массив не читается из UserDefaults?

Comment: При сохранении выбранных элементов приложение падает, думаю что наверное сохранение не правильно. Подкорректировать здесь пока не могу

Comment: И сохранение в конкретную ячейку тож не пойму

Comment: если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь сохранить свой класс Exersise в NSUserDefaults? если так, то ваш класс должен иметь методы `encodeWithCoder` и `initWithCoder`, которые должны кодировать и декодировать все переменные, которые надо сохранить и загрузить. Другими словами объяснять системе что такое сохранение и загрузка для этого типа объекта. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: исправил ответ.

Comment: @ArturSkachkov - если ответ решил вашу проблему - отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе Exersise вам надо написать два метода приведенные ниже (заменить все объекты на реальные объекты из вашего класса), и убедиться, что в Exersise прописан протокол NSCoding

```
class customObject: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var custom: String!
    var anotherCustom: Int!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.custom = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("custom") as! String
        self.anotherCustom = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("anotherCustom") as! Int

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        [aCoder .encodeObject(self.custom, forKey: "custom")]
        [aCoder .encodeObject(self.anotherCustom, forKey: "anotherCustom")]
    }    
}
```

Сохранение

```
var data:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.customObject)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "customObject")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Загрузка

```
let newData:NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("customObject") as! NSData
let newObj:customObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(newData) as! customObject
```

Если у вас массив таких объектов, в целом ничего не меняется:

Сохранение

```
var arr: [customObject]!
//populate array
var data:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.arr)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "customObject")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Загрузка

```
let newData:NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("customObject") as! NSData
let newArr:Array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(newData) as! [customObject]
var newObject:customObject = newArr[0] //и так далее
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37110/discussion-on-answer-by-max-mikheyenko-----).

Comment: @PashaPash галочку то зачем было убирать

Comment: Галочку модераторы снять не могут. Ее снял автор вопроса.

Comment: тем более - напугали человека так, что он с хорошего ответа галочку убрал

Comment: Я тут ни при чем, просто комменты в чат унес :)

Comment: Макс, я очень извиняюсь :) нечаянно